# All outputs end up the same in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying to iterate over `key` which has been entered into the command line. During the iteration, I want to create 2 strings, `upper` and `lower`, which can be used later. The problem is that key, `upper` and `lower` are all ending up with the same outputs. Could someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{  
    if (argc != 2)  
    {  
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n"); // if no key is entered on command line, end program and say key  
        return 0;  
    }  

    string key = argv[1]; // convert command to key for ease  
    string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";  // lowercase alphabet  
    string cap_alpha ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; //uppercase alphabet   
    string lower = argv[1]; // gives string correct length to edit later  
    string upper = argv[1]; // ^ditto  

    if (strlen(key) != 26) // if key is not exactly 26 char, end program and say it must contain 26  
    {  
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters\n");  
        return 0;  
    }  

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) //iterates through key  
    {  
        if (key[i] < 'A' || (key[i] > 'Z' && key[i] < 'a') || key[i] > 'z') //if key includes non alphabet characters, ends command  
        {  
            printf("Key must only contain alphabetic characters.\n");  
            return 0;  
        }  

        else if (key[i] >= 'A' && key[i] <= 'Z')  
        {  
            lower[i] += 32; // if char in key is uppercase, convert to lowercase, add to string "lower"  
            upper[i] = key[i]; // if char in key is uppercase, keeps as uppercase  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            upper[i] = key[i] - 32; // if char in key is lowercase, changes to uppercase  
            lower[i] = key[i];  
        }  
    }  

    printf("key: %s\n", key); // test output  
    printf("lower: %s\n", lower); //test output  
    printf("upper: %s\n", upper); // test output  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assigning strings doesn't make copies, it just assigns a pointer to the same string. So `key`, `upper`, `lower`, and `argv[1]` are all the same string. When you make a change to one of them, it affects all of them.

You need to make copies first.

```
size_t len = strlen(key) + 1; // +1 for the null byte
char upper[len], lower[len];
strcpy(upper, key);
strcpy(lower, key);
```

BTW, C has functions `isalpha()`, `isupper()`, `islower()`, `toupper()`, and `tolower()`. You should use these instead of relying on the specifics of ASCII coding.